# Servlet: get query string but just return empty

Tags: java, servlets

I'm using mediator design pattern for my web project. There is a front controller to take care all requests, and base on each request to find suitable servlet. In web.xml, I try this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then a request like  *localhost:8080/project_name/a/b/c/d.jsp* I want to get the string `a/b/c/d.jsp` but when I use:
`request.getServletPath()` I get empty string.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `getPathInfo()` method instead

[getServletPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath()) method will return an empty string ("") if the servlet used to process this request was matched using the "/*" pattern.

[getPathInfo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo()) method returns path information follows the servlet path but precedes the query string and will start with a "/" character.